# Can I set different passwords for different desktop environments?

Tags: environment

I have installed GNOME, Unity and Cairo Dock desktop environments. I wanted to set different passwords for each. Is this possible by any means? Thank you.

Comment: No not possible at all, but you can create users like this , **user_Gnome, User_Unity, User_dock** if you want Desktop Environment specific user ( more pleasing too), though all can access every other DE .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the password to access the login is for the user, not the window manager it uses, I think your only options is create different users and set the default environment for each user.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible without having different user accounts as well.

The login manager is what verifies your user account at login, it has nothing to do with the desktop manager. What you can do is have three different users with each having the different desktop environment set as default. Using Ubuntu One, you could even keep all your files in sync (or give each user rights to each others folder and use rsync, but Ubuntu One is easier).

EDIT: darent beat me by seconds.

Comment: Edit: A for effort :)